# Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unexpected response, code=404, content-type=""

Tags: ruby, selenium

I am trying to execute some tests using **archani** for auto login plugin and intermittently I see this error Has anyone else also experienced this issue? If yes, what are possible ways of resolving?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar (if not the same) issue. I'm not sure what is your exact error (next row), because you haven't added it, mine was `Unable to load Atom 'execute_script' from file './third_party/webdriver-atoms/execute_script.js'`. And resolution was just to update `phantomjs`, which I did just by running `npm install -g phantomjs`.

That was it. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Acko, let me check